# CSS form highlighting for error validation

Tags: css, forms, validation, highlight

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ajax-html5-css3-contact-form-tutorial/
I have this form on one of my websites but the way they made this is complicated for me. i want to know if there is any way that i could have the validation for the input boxes red when the user makes a mistake. something like this http://jsfiddle.net/3UCbw/1/ i just want to highlight the boxes red when the user makes a mistake thats it. thanks any help would be appreciate it!

this is the code i have for the highlight.

```
div.highlight {
-webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px black; 
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black; 
 box-shadow:5px 5px 5px black; 
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px red; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px red; 
 box-shadow:0 0 15px red; 
 }
```

you can take a look at the form at the link on the top!
maybe is something easy in the jquery just to highlight the boxes thanks!

Comment: A question titled "ajax php form with jquery" should have some AJAX, PHP, or jQuery code in it somewhere.

Comment: the code is in the website on the link thanks.

Comment: I changed the title to something more suitable

Comment: thanks for a better  title. i appreciate the help.

Comment: you mean something like this? [http://jsfiddle.net/3UCbw/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/3UCbw/16/) or maybe i don't get you question...

Comment: if you take a look at the form on the tutorial (the link is in the question) try to implement the highlight in there when the user makes a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.fn.extend({
    ensure: function(regex, failClass){
        return this.each(function(){
            if(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input"){
                $(this).change(function(){
                    var $input = $(this);
                    var val = $input.val().toUpperCase();                    
                    if(regex.test(val)){
                        $input.removeClass(failClass)
                    } else { 
                        $input.addClass(failClass);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

var emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/
$('#email').ensure(emailRegex, 'error');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CharlesTWall3/SFV3s/25/